# postrender event from Vectorlayer does not work with openlayers 6

Tags: layer, backbone-events, openlayers-6

We are using openlayer 6.3.1 und want to use "postrender" event from Layer Api, but it does not work right.

The code is like this:

```
vectorLayer.on("postrender", this.moveFeature);
......
moveFeature: function (event) {
    console.log(event);
...
```

**The console log message will not show.**

But if i change the code to:

```
vectorLayer.on("postrender", console.log("test"));
```

**the log message "test" will be shown in console,**

If i change the code to:

```
vectorLayer.on("postrender", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

there is also **no console messages**, what could be the problem? Our project is backbone basis, and we use many backbone event, i dont know if it make some troubles.

Comment: Does the layer have any features visible in the view extent?  If there is nothing to be rendered there won't be an event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to see if there are features visible in the view extent?

Answer (score 0):

Your layer is probably already rendered. You can call `render` on the map **after** declaring your event.

```js
function animate(event) {
  // your logic here

  // Rerender to loop
  map.render();
}
this.vectorLayer.on('postrender', animate);
map.render();
```